# How to find name for argument of WinActivate

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I'm writing a script that will fill in a form in Microsoft Edge. I know I should use `WinActivate` to change focus, but I don't know how to find out what the argument should be? For example if I go to Stackoverflow I can sort of guess it would be like `Stack Overflow - Microsoft Edge` but if the title is longer it gets truncated in the toolbar and I honestly don't know where I can go to see the full title of a process? I tried Task Manager.

Is there a better way? It seems a bit hacky to rely on the title of the program, especially when the title of the website determines it.

Basically I'm asking, how do you use WinActive to change focus?

```
Process, Exist, MicrosoftEdge.exe
EdgePID = %ErrorLevel%
if( EdgePID )
{
    MsgBox, Edge is running, with PID: %EdgePID%
}
WinGetTitle, Title , ahk_pid %EdgePID%
MsgBox, Title: %Title%
IfWinExist, %Title%
    WinActivate ; this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the process name which should be always the same. I'm assuming the name for Microsoft Edge is *MicrosoftEdge.exe*, change it if your process is named differently.

First get the process *PID*, which is stored in `ErrorLevel`:

```
Process, Exist, MicrosoftEdge.exe
EdgePID = %ErrorLevel%
if( EdgePID 
{
    MsgBox, Edge is running, with PID: %EdgePID%
}
```

Then get the window title of that process, using the special command `ahk_pid`:

```
WinGetTitle, Title , ahk_pid %EdgePID%
MsgBox, Title: %Title%
```

The window can be activated using the same method:

```
WinActivate, ahk_pid %EdgePID%
```

Alternatively the process name can be used directly:

```
WinActivate, ahk_exe MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

Comment: Thanks but what if there are multiple windows of the same Edge process open?

Comment: @Dlittle In that case I believe the window that was active last, should be activated.

Comment: The last part doesn't seem to work and Edge isn't open. I posted the code in the main question.

Comment: Also, does WinActivate work if it's minimized or only if it's in the background?